# I need help figuring out how to get the code to give a triple gaussian distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, gaussian

So the purpose of my code is to use inputted data points to give a gaussian plot distribution. I figured out how to make it work with a double gaussian but I'm having a lot of trouble adding a third. Im not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. 1 of the errors I keep getting is an Index Error saying that the list index is out of range. I would appreciate any help with this.

Heres my code:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from scipy.stats import iqr
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys


matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'

fitfunc_triple = lambda p, x: np.abs(p[0]) * exp(-0.5 * ((x - p[1]) / p[2]) ** 2) + np.abs(p[3]) * exp(
    -0.5 * ((x - p[4]) / p[5]) ** 2) + np.abs(p[6]) * exp(-0.5 * ((x - p[7])/ p[8] **2 ))
fitfunc_double = lambda p, x: np.abs(p[0]) * exp(-0.5 * ((x - p[1]) / p[2]) ** 2) + np.abs(p[3]) * exp(
    -0.5 * ((x - p[4]) / p[5]) ** 2)
fitfunc_single = lambda p, x: np.abs(p[0]) * exp(-0.5 * ((x - p[1]) / p[2]) ** 2)
errfunc = lambda p, x, y: (y - fitfunc(p, x))


dataR = np.loadtxt("/Users/Safi/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2018.1/scratches/rspecial1385.a2261.dat5", skiprows=0)


RA = dataR[:, 0]
DEC = dataR[:, 1]
VELR = dataR[:, 2]
REDSH = dataR[:, 3]
RADD = dataR[:, 4]
sl = 3E5
zbar = np.mean(REDSH)
vc = zbar * sl
VEL = vc + sl * ((REDSH - zbar) / (1 + zbar))


wdith = 200
iters = 10
sig2 = 500

binN = int(math.ceil((np.max(VEL) - np.min(VEL)) / wdith))
sys.stdout = open(str(wdith) + "_1sigma_" + str(iters) + "_sig2_" + str(sig2) + ".txt", "w")

plt.figure(1)
y, x, _ = plt.hist(VEL, binN, alpha=0.5, label='data')
x = (x[1:] + x[:-1]) / 2  # for len(x)==len(y)
data = np.vstack((x, y)).T

xdata = data[:, 0]
ydata = data[:, 1]
yerr = ydata ** 0.5

init = [10, 69500, 1200, 5, 68000, sig2]
bds = ([0, 66000, 800, 0, 66000, sig2], [50, 70000, 1750, 20, 70000, sig2 + 0.01])


def index_outlier(data):
    inter_quart = iqr(data) * 1.5
    bd2 = np.percentile(data, 75) + inter_quart
    bd1 = np.percentile(data, 25) - inter_quart
    index = []
    for i in [i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x < bd1 or x > bd2]:
        index.append(i)
    return (index)


#### Bootstrapping Estimation Function ####
def fit_bootstrap(fitfunc, datax, datay, init, bds, sigma, iterations=iters):
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y: (y - fitfunc(p, x))

    # Fit first time
    pfit = least_squares(errfunc, init, bounds=bds, args=(datax, datay), max_nfev=10000)
    model = fitfunc(pfit.x, datax)
    residuals = pfit.fun

    # Random data sets are generated and fitted
    ps = []
    for i in range(iterations):
        randomdataY = []
        for k in range(len(sigma)):
            randomDelta = np.random.normal(0., sigma[k], 1)
            randomdataY.append(datay[k] + randomDelta)
            out = np.concatenate(randomdataY)
        randomfit = least_squares(errfunc, init, bounds=bds, args=(datax, out))
        ps.append(randomfit.x)

        # Removing outliers
    # Finding outliers and indexing them
    master_list = []
    indexed = []
    for k in range(len(ps[0])):  # 0-6
        it = []
        for i in range(len(ps)):  # 0-1000
            it.append(ps[i][k])
        master_list.append(it)
    #        indexed.append(index_outlier(master_list[k]))

    #    # List of outlier indicies
    #    flat_list=[item for sublist in indexed for item in sublist]
    #    no_dups= list(set(flat_list))

    #    # Removing bad fits
    #    for k in range(len(master_list)):
    #        for i in sorted(no_dups,reverse=True):
    #            del master_list[k][i]

    pfit_bootstrap = []
    perr_bootstrap = []
    for i in master_list:
        pfit_bootstrap.append(np.median(i))
        perr_pos = np.round(np.percentile(i, 84) - np.median(i), 4)
        perr_neg = np.round(np.median(i) - np.percentile(i, 16), 4)
        perr_bootstrap.append(str('[+') + str(perr_pos) + str(',-') + str(perr_neg) + str(']'))

    return (pfit_bootstrap, perr_bootstrap, residuals, pfit.nfev, master_list)


pfit, perr, residuals, nfev, master_list = fit_bootstrap(fitfunc_double, xdata, ydata, init, bds, yerr)
pfit1, perr1, residuals1, nfev1, master_list1 = fit_bootstrap(fitfunc_single, xdata, ydata, init, bds, yerr)
more_data = np.linspace(np.min(xdata), np.max(xdata), 1000)
real_func = fitfunc_double(pfit, more_data)
real_func1 = fitfunc_single(pfit1, more_data)

######## Saving Coefficients #########
A1 = pfit[0]
m1 = pfit[1]
s1 = pfit[2]
A2 = pfit[3]
m2 = pfit[4]
s2 = pfit[5]
A3 = pfit[6]
m3 = pfit[7]
s3 = pfit[8]

pecp = VEL - vc
m1p = m1 - vc
m2p = m2 - vc
m3p = m3 - vc
xdatap = xdata - vc


plt.figure(6)
plt.hist(pecp, binN, alpha=.5, label='data', color='skyblue')
xhmax = np.amax(pecp + 1500)
xhmin = np.amin(pecp - 1500)
xh = np.linspace(xhmin, xhmax, 50)
# yh1=(mlab.normpdf(xh, c[1], c[2]))
yh1 = np.abs(A1) * exp(-0.5 * (((xh - m1p) / (s1)) ** 2))
yh2 = np.abs(A2) * exp(-0.5 * (((xh - m2p) / (s2)) ** 2))
yh3 = np.abs(A3) * exp(-0.5 * (((xh - m3p) / (s3)) ** 2))
plt.plot(xh, yh1, color='b', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(xh, yh2, color='r', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(xh, yh3, color='g', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(xh, yh1 + yh2 + yh3, color='purple', linewidth=3)
# plt.errorbar(xdatap,y,xerr=wdith/2,ls='none', yerr=yerr,color='k',linewidth=2)
# plt.plot(xdatap, ydata,'.',color='k')
plt.ylim(0, np.max(ydata) + 2)
plt.xlabel('Peculiar Velocity (km/s)')
plt.ylabel('N$_{gal}$')
plt.text(-4800, 15, '$\mu_{2}$-$\mu_{1}$ = ' + str(int(m2 - m1)) + ' km/s')
plt.savefig(str(wdith) + "_1sigma_" + str(iters) + "_sig2_" + str(sig2) + "_hist.ps")


divi = -1800

memlow = np.array([[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(1)])
memhigh = np.array([[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(1)])
j = 0
k = 0

plt.show()
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: You should consider adding a minimum example, this is too much code.